# How to join two tables into a asp.net gridview based on ID

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, webforms, .net-4.8

this is my first time asking a question here.

I'm having a trouble with my gridview.

Here is the thing: I have a web application for check list and the user can have multiple projects and every project have it's own tasks.
What I'm trying to do is in the home page where I show the user his projects I want to grid view to show all projects and the number of tasks

The problem here is I have two tables: 1- tbl_projects, 2- tbl_tasks. The tasks table has foreign key connected with the project id in the projects table.


I tried to write this query in SqlDataSource, but it doesn't work.

```
Select tbl_projects.*, tbl_tasks.* from tbl_projects, tbl_tasks 
where tbl_projects.USER_ID = @USER_ID and tbl_projects.FAVORITE = @FAVORITE and tbl_tasks.PROJECT_ID = tbl_projects.PROJECT_ID
```

*And I'm sorry if my writing is bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
Select *   from tbl_projects
inner join tbl_tasks on tbl_tasks.PROJECT_ID = tbl_projects.PROJECT_ID
where tbl_projects.USER_ID = @USER_ID and tbl_projects.FAVORITE = @FAVORITE
```

Comment: I know this is old answer but I want to ask if I can use both `username` on different table?

Comment: @新Acesyyy I am sorry but what is both username. I can't see any username here

Comment: Just tried it the `inner join` with two columns named as `username` but it didnt work for `login`, btw im not the OP. just searching some answers